# What does "mulmod" do in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, math

I've seen `mulmod` used in Mikhail Vladimirov's [Math in Solidity](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-3-percents-and-proportions-4db014e080b1) series:

```
function fullMul(uint256 x, uint256 y) public pure returns (uint256 l, uint256 h) {
    uint256 mm = mulmod(x, y, uint256(-1));
    l = x * y;
    h = mm - l;
    if (mm < l) h -= 1;
}
```

What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Solidity cheatsheet](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/cheatsheet.html), `mulmod` is a function available at the global scope.

> `mulmod(uint x, uint y, uint k) returns (uint)`: compute `(x * y) % k` where the multiplication is performed with arbitrary precision and does not wrap around at 2**256. Assert that `k != 0` starting from version 0.5.0.

Some examples:

1. `mulmod(3, 4, 5)` is equal to 2.
2. `mulmod(2**256 - 1, 1, type(uint256).max)` is equal to 0.
3. `mulmod(2**255, 2**255, type(uint256).max)` is equal to 1.

Notice that even if `2**255 * 2**255` overflows, the contract call doesn't revert in Solidity v0.8.

Comment: The third example (`mulmod(2**255, 2**255, type(uint256).max)`) does not result in 1. The result is :
0x4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000